# javascript slideshow in magento static block

Tags: javascript, magento, slider, block

I would like to use some easy javascript plugin on my magento page.
I found one realey simple and nice and its working on my simple html page like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 1" />
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <a href="http://www.menucool.com"><img src="3.jpg" /></a>
        <img src="4.jpg" />
        <img src="5.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 5" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then I wanted to use it in magento. I have a static block that is displayed on homepage so I used this code there : `{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/-slideshow.phtml"}}`

I put all images,scritps,css to same folder to be sure there is no mistake here. Well on my page it shows all images horizontaly but no slideshow effect.
Maybe the javascript link code has to put somewhere else.
Do you have experience in that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i am just giving your idea to make it because in static block you didn't assing path for skin js folder and css folder so please try to do like this way,

**// Add this to your template file**

```
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/bannerRotator.js');?>"></script>
<script  src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js');?>"></script>

<script language="javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    bannerRotator('#bannerRotator', 500, 5000, true);
  });
</script>
```

**// Add this part only in static block**

```
<div id="slider">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 1" />
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <a href="http://www.menucool.com"><img src="3.jpg" /></a>
        <img src="4.jpg" />
        <img src="5.jpg" alt="Caption for slide 5" />
    </div>
```

hope this will help to solve your issue.